# excel Replace selected txt in one cell with txt from another cell

Tags: excel

In excel

A1 I have a case CR05 for camera ??????

A2 I have a case CR05 for camera ??????

On line one I want to replace the CR05 with 1234 
on line two I want to replace the CR05 with 1235 and so on

The 1234 is in a cell  A1 & the 1235 in A2 and so on

Comment: Sorry, what values do you have in which cells? (And what exactly is your question?)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for SUBSTITUTE?

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"CR05",A1)
```

It replaces the text "CR05" with whatever is in cell A1 for the string in B1.  (I made the assumption your string "I have a case CR05 for camera ??????" was in B1.)